# How can I connect to wireless printer Epson XP-225?

Tags: wireless, epson

I'm trying to set up a Wi-Fi printer Epson XP-225. I've gone to system settings (`unity-control-center`), selected "Printers", then "Add" and then "Network Printer". I don't see the printer listed there and when I select "Find Network Printer", I am asked to enter the host, but I have no idea what to enter here.

I have installed the Linux driver provided by Epson (http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=43353&DSCCHK=9f26e5cbd41612f9e38f91537c63c82d18c401e9).

What should I do? I'm quite lost.

Answer (score 2):

A printer that attaches wirelessly is given an IP address by the router. Check your own Ubuntu machine from the terminal:

```
ifconfig
```

You will see the IP address your own computer has on the network. It may be, as an example, 192.168.0.15. Likewise, your printer has a different IP address of its own. You can find the address by pressing the 'network status' button on the printer. This is explained on page 14 here: http://content.etilize.com/User-Manual/1028142396.pdf

A network status page will be printed that will give you, among other things, the needed IP address.

Then add a network printer as before and use the Device URI of: `ipp://192.168.0.11:631/lpr` but substitute the IP address you found from the printer for my example 192.168.0.11. The port number, 631, needs to be specified as that is the port number that the CUPS printing system uses.

Then you can go forward with the configuration, select the make, model and driver and print a test page.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it work just installing drivers (they gave couple errors though as I am running 16.04 and some newer softwares), installing scanner program from Ubuntu´s Applications and last editing following SANE file through terminal:

*sudo gedit /etc/sane.d/epson.conf*

And I did add there my printers static ip settings (autodiscovery in case that you use DHCP on your router):

*net 192.168.2.2* (Check yours from the printer)
*net autodiscovery*

I had also epson2.conf file and you may want to edit that too if not working or just to be sure. Just add the same line(s).

"SANE (Scanner Access Now Easy) is the linux way of scanning. sane supports a great many scanners, and the community around SANE adds support for more scanners all the time. By and large, most supported scanners are plug and play simple (plug them in and your ready to scan). However, some scanners will require manual installation."

Answer (score 0):

- Uninstall existing xp225 printer.
- Re-install and when you get the option "connect by wifi or usb.
- Select wifi.

It asks to insert usb cable this enables you to connect to the printer.  It then searches for the router.
Select your router. Then it asks you for the wep code or password.

- Insert wep code or password then it does sync up.

Just follow the remainder of the install & asks to remove usb cable.  I had the same problem as many users but this does work.

Bonus when set up was complete, I plugged usb cable in and it worked fine to my pc. Best of luck.