# How to install Epson printer drivers on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: drivers, printing, 16.04, epson

I am having trouble to set up my Epson printer on Ubuntu 16.04. How can I install the drivers?

Answer (score 24):

- Step 1: Download the driver for your printer. (In my case I download it from https://www.openprinting.org/printers/manufacturer/Epson/.)
- Step 2: Add trusty repositories.

  1. Open a terminal and type the following command:

     ```
     sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
     ```
  2. Add the following line at the bottom of the file:

     ```
     deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main
     ```
  3. Save with Control+X, Y, and ENTER
  4. Run the command:

     ```
     sudo apt-get update
     ```
- Step 3: Install lsb with

  ```
  sudo apt-get install lsb
  ```
- Step 4: Install the printer driver. Run:

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i yourdriver.deb
  ```
- Step 5: Remove the trusty repos from sources.list

  1. Open a terminal and type the following command:

     ```
     sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
     ```
  2. Remove the following line at the bottom of the file:

     ```
     deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main
     ```
  3. Save with Control+X, Y, and ENTER
  4. Run:

     ```
     sudo apt-get update
     ```
- Step 6: Add your printer by going into Printers > Add.

**NOTE**: You may have to manually select the driver from a list.

Here's the proof on how this worked out:

[image]

Comment: Steps 2 and 4 may be optional, but otherwise this certainly does the trick.

Comment: Why did ubuntu remove the drivers from xenial?

Comment: Great Answer! I wish I found it earlier. I followed the instructions on this site: https://tutorialforlinux.com/2019/04/02/driver-epson-l355-ubuntu-19-04-how-to-download-install/. But not sure if this was the best way to install the printer.

Answer (score 5):

There are printer driver and printer driver utility you should search for your model on the [Epson website](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule).

For instance for my model l310.

[printer driver](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=34541&DSCCHK=141ba614c212ead0099d27f8dc8f2bc35faf7781)

[printer driver utility](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=57789&DSCCHK=60fe10bf4a65129cde4dbf5c76d374e2a654d411)

I just installed them and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The following instructions will allow you to add software from wily that is not available in xenial. You will also receive any software updates and security patches. By configuring apt-preferences, the system will always favor xenial and will only install from wily when absolutely necessary.

Before you get started, make a backup of your sources.list file:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sourcesbackup
```

**PART ONE:**

First, run the following commands to append lines to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
echo 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily main' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
echo 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates main' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
echo 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-security main' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

---

**PART TWO:**

Next, create an apt-preferences file:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/preferences
```

Now, copy and paste the following into the file:

```
Package: *
Pin: release n=wily
Pin-Priority: 400

Package: *
Pin: release n=wily-updates
Pin-Priority: 400

Package: *
Pin: release n=wily-security
Pin-Priority: 400
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to save the file. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to exit nano.

---

**PART THREE:**

Run the following commands to install dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdebi lsb lsb-base lsb-core lsb-cxx lsb-desktop lsb-graphics lsb-invalid-mta lsb-languages lsb-multimedia lsb-printing lsb-release lsb-security
```

---

**PART FOUR:**

Go to [the Epson website](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX), search for your specific model and set the operating system to Linux.

Click on each of the download links, accept the user agreement, and then download the amd64.deb or the i386.deb file.

Use `gdebi` to install the deb files in a terminal.

**example:**

```
sudo gdebi ~/Downloads/epson-inkjet-printer-201203w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb
```

If you download the iscan .deb.tar.gz file, right click on the file in nautilus and select "extract here". Open the newly extracted archive and locate the `install.sh` file. Use `sudo` to run the `install.sh` file in a terminal.

Comment: Ok, did the sudo gdebi, seems to work. Now what?

Comment: @TMOTTM Now you can use your printer. If it installed correctly, you should be able to go to system settings > printers > add printer.

Comment: I see. I tried that as well, but that's still pretty not obvious how to do. What should I enter for the 'Host' to find the printer'

Comment: @TMOTTM Is this what you are looking for? https://askubuntu.com/a/768459/167115