# Epson L575 printer does not print on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, printing, 16.10, epson

I've followed the steps from [this tutorial](http://tutorialforlinux.com/2016/02/07/how-to-install-epson-l575-printer-driver-software-utility-on-ubuntu-linux/) and [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771427/how-to-install-epson-printer-drivers-on-ubuntu-16-04) to install Epson L575 printer's drivers on Ubuntu 16.10.

Then I looked for the printer in the network and it was found, with an address similar to `dnssd://EPSON%20L575%20Series._ipp._tcp.local/?uuid=af92100-67c4-11d4-a45f-44d24402454f`. Yet, if I send a job to it, it is declared as disconnected!

I tried to add it as an IPP printer, using its IP address, as in `ipp://192.168.0.33`. In this case, the printer is found but nothing is printed and the job stays as "Pending."

Epson Printer Utility can print a page through its "Jet Verification" option.

The output of `tail -f /var/log/cups/access_log` has not much of interest, except maybe by this line:

> localhost - - [18/Jan/2017:19:51:16 -0300] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 219 Pause-Printer client-error-not-found

In `/var/log/cups/error_log`, I find this:

> E [18/Jan/2017:19:36:35 -0300] [Job 21] Print job was not accepted.

Not only the printer is pingable, I can access its web interface via browser.

How can I make this printer work?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the autodiscovery fails but I got it to work with the IPP URI. I just to add `/ipp/printer` after the IP. So, the address that was

```
ipp://192.168.0.33
```

changed to

```
ipp://192.168.0.33/ipp/printer
```

Here is a screenshot from where I change it:

[image: Screenshot of configuration screen where the printer URI can be changed.]

Comment: in my case I needed `/ipp/print` instead