# Can't install Epson wf-4630 Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, apt, dpkg, printing, scanner

I am experiencing a problem trying to install an `Epson WF-4630 All-In-One driver(s)`. I have been referencing the tutorial found at [How to install Epson printer drivers on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771427/how-to-install-epson-printer-drivers-on-ubuntu-16-04).

I get an error message on step four,

```
dpkg: error processing archive yourdriver.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 yourdriver.deb
```

I tried typing the driver file download name, `epson-inkjet-printer-es....11-1lsb3.2_amd64-2.deb` and received the following error message,

```
dpkg: error processing archive epson-inkjet-printer-es....11-1lsb32_amd64-2.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 epson-inkjet-printer-es....11-1lsb32_amd64-2.deb
```

I also referenced the video tutorial here, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2ONxicbwP4. My system does not accommodate the `auto-install` feature and downloaded driver files ope in `Read Only mode`.

Does anyone have any suggestions or resources to overcome this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Okay, so as soon as I posted this, I was able install most, but not all of the drivers I require.  The scan driver is a different file download and appears to require "Root Privilege" to install.  I know this is risky and not sure how to access the root to complete scanner driver installation.  Any guidance would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to include this link to Epson's installation instructions.  http://download.ebz.epson.net/man/linux/iscan_e.html#sec6-1

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

1. Download:  epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.4.1-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb

   ```
   from: www.openprinting.org/printer/Epson/Epson-WF-4630_series
   ```
2. Add trusty repositories:

   A.  sudo  nano  /etc/apt/sources.list

   B.  Add the following line to the end of the file:

   ```
   deb  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/  trusty  main
   ```

   C.  sudo  apt-get  update
3. Run:    sudo  apt-get  install lsb
4. sudo  dpkg  -i  epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.4.1-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb
5. Remove the trusty repositories:

   A.  sudo  nano  /etc/apt/sources.list

   B.  Remove the line you entered above.

   C.  Run:    sudo  apt-get  update
6. Use SystemSettings->Printers to install the printer. Mine was a network printer.
7. For some reason, the print was very light until I changed the printer options and selected media type of "plain papers-High".  Then it seemed to print at normal strength.