# How to install EPL-6200L in 16.04

Tags: printing, epson

My Epson EPL-6200L works great in 14.04, and I am trying to install it in 16.04. Downloaded `openprinting-ppds-postscript-epson_20130226-1lsb3.2_all.deb` from http://openprinting.org, and installed with GDebi. That installs a bunch of `.gz` files for various printers into `/usr/share/ppd/OpenPrinting-Epson/Epson`. I extracted the one that corresponds to the 6200L, copied  the `ppd` file into `/etc/cups/ppd`, went to System Settings to add the printer as usual, selected the `ppd` file as usual (just like in 14.04), and nothing. It just doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Epson printer drivers on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771427/how-to-install-epson-printer-drivers-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 1):

OpenPrinting is a good source of information for printing support on Linux. [Epson EPL-6200 | OpenPrinting](http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Epson/Epson-EPL-6200) says your printer should work perfectly. The link says the driver is postscript-epson [Postscript-Epson | OpenPrinting](http://www.openprinting.org/driver/Postscript-Epson) and the details there say you just need a PPD file.

1. So download that for the 6200.
2. Go to *Printers* folder, click *Add*, follow the guide through and select the PPD file.
3. Traditionally, installed PPDs are in `/etc/cups/ppd`. The database is in `/usr/share/ppd`. So if you can open the folder `ppd` that is inside `cups` that is in `/etc` and save the downloaded PPD file there.
4. Then, as you follow the install guide, you look for the *Use PPD file* option and point the system to the PPD.

Comment: Sorry for the vague question. I tried what you suggested: I downloaded openprinting-ppds-postscript-epson_20130226-1lsb3.2_all.deb from openprinting.org, and ran it with gdebi. That installs a bunch of .gz files in usr/share/ppd/OpenPrinting-Epson/Epson. One corresponded to my EPL-6200, and I extracted it and moved the ppd file into etc/cups/ppd. Then I went to System Settings and added the printer as usual, and selected the ppd file as usual. I had my hopes up, because it all looked good. Nothing. The printer still sits there like a stone. Works great in 14.04, nada in 16.04. Thanks.

Comment: hmmmm. not sure I have instant solutions. When I look at the page again, I see an "install" button and half-way down that page https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/openprinting/database/driverpackages one can add the source as a link; not a now-solution. I see the readme in the package you downloaded says one can just download a ppd; but as you say, within the package are compressed ppd; if one un-compresses; and placed it, cups should find it. If you go here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems and maybe go to CUPS error log, you can see what errors the system is reporting;

Comment: as I re-read the debugging wiki, there is a "troubleshooting" Wizard: go to PRINTERS folder; choose HELP on the top menu bar; F1 or troubleshooting should activate the wizard; your feedback may help others

Comment: Tried it again with the CUPS Error Log going, and I can't tell much. However, here's a bit that caught my attention:                                              
"D [05/Nov/2017:21:12:51 +0800] [Client 2] HTTP_STATE_WAITING Closing for error 32 (Broken pipe)
D [05/Nov/2017:21:12:51 +0800] [Client 2] Closing connection." Does this mean anything helpful?

Comment: sorry: doesn't mean much to me; surprising 16.04 won't work; as an LTS, it has been very good otherwise; Linux Mint now bases all their releases on LTS; I see the Zorin folks do the same;