# How do I install drivers for Epson WF-3720 all-in-one under Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, package-management

I just purchased a new Epson WF-3720 all-in-one to use with a System 76 Sable running Ubuntu 16.04 and have made several attempts to get working drivers installed.

I am posting documentation of my current attempt in hope of getting some assistance and create a forum thread that will be helpful to others

Starting from this page:
[How-to Install Epson WF 3720 Ubuntu 16.04 & Quick-Start Scanning](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2017/08/02/how-to-install-epson-wf-3720-ubuntu-16-04-quick-start-scanning/)

Following the link in step one takes us here on the Epson site:
[Download Printer Driver  ESC/P-R Driver 2 (generic driver) | Epson - drivers & downloads](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=70756&DSCCHK=3d57bc5baade8f3f2c41d91e8b696c9b66e574e4)

After accepting licensing terms we get choice of downloads. The one that appears to be best fit is epson-inkjet-printer-escpr2_1.0.13-1lsb3.2_i386.deb , so we download it.

There is an instruction to install LSB package (version 3.2 or later) before the .deb file, so we do that after running sudo apt-get clean, sudo apt-get autoremove, sudo apt-get update, and sudo apt-get upgrade to clean up after previous installation attempts.

Now we try to install LSB in this terminal session:

```
rodgers@rodgers-Sable:~$ sudo # apt-get install lsb

usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V

usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]

usage: sudo -l [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user]
            [command]

usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p
            prompt] [-u user] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]

usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p
            prompt] [-u user] file ...
```

This is strange looking, we ask for an informed opinion on whether this appears ok so far before proceeding to install the .deb file.

Update:

We have been informed the # comments out the rest of the command, so we try again:

~$ sudo apt-get install lsb

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

lsb is already the newest version (9.20160110ubuntu0.2).

lsb set to manually installed.

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.

So we already have LSB.

Double clicking epson-inkjet-printer-escpr2_1.0.13-1lsb3.2_i386.deb and choosing Install returns this:

Detailed errors from the package manager follow:

apt transaction returned result exit-failed

Any advise at this point would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please try `sudo apt-get install lsb` instead (without the `#` that introduces a comment)?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/771427/how-to-install-epson-printer-drivers-on-ubuntu-16-04